# running a C program on an MPI cluster

Tags: linux, mpi, cluster-computing, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem running an MPI program (written in C or C++) over a cluster comprising of two nodes. 
Details: 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
No. of nodes: 2 (master and slave)

Everything works well. When I run a simple **mpi_hello** program on the cluster with 12 as an argument (no. of processes) I see 4 **mpi-hello** instances running on the slave node (checked using **top**).

[Output on master node + mpi_hello instances running on the second node (slave node)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xF9M.png)
When I try to run another program (for instance a simple program calculating and printing prime numbers in a range) it is running on the master node but i don't see any instances of it on the slave node.

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
//#include</usr/include/c++/5/iostream>
#include<mpi.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int N, i, j, isPrime;
clock_t begin = clock();

int myrank, nprocs;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

printf("Hello from the processor %d of %d \n" , myrank, nprocs);


printf("To print all prime numbers between 1 to N\n");
    printf("Enter the value of N\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    /* For every number between 2 to N, check 
    whether it is prime number or not */
    printf("Prime numbers between %d to %d\n", 1, N);

    for(i = 2; i <= N; i++){
        isPrime = 0;
        /* Check whether i is prime or not */
        for(j = 2; j <= i/2; j++){
             /* Check If any number between 2 to i/2 divides I 
              completely If yes the i cannot be prime number */
             if(i % j == 0){
                 isPrime = 1;
                 break;
             }
        }

        if(isPrime==0 && N!= 1)
            printf("%d ",i);
    }

clock_t end = clock();
double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("\nThe time spent by the program is %f\n" , time_spent);

while(1)
{}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;

}
```

What could be the possible reasons behind it ? 
Are there any other ways to check if it is running on the slave node as well ?
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised this is due to `stdin` not being connected to all MPI processes. Just try to get rid of the `scanf()` and pass the value as a command line argument.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, I now hardcoded the value in the program. And it is shown working on the second node. But I don't see any advantage. The same program when run on a single node without using MPI is faster (takes half the time) compared to when it is run in parallel (using MPI). Maybe I am not implementing the parallelism properly. Could u point out any issues in the code ? The code is the same as above...  Thanks

Comment: There is no work sharing into your code: you don't distribute the work among the MPI processes; all processes to the whole work. Therefore, there is no chance to get any sort of speed-up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is a code I worked with. A vector containing first 500 integers. Now I want to divide them into 4 processes equally (i.e. each process gets 125 integers -- the first process gets 1-125, the second 126-250 and so on). I tried to use MPI_Scatter(). but I don't see the data equally divided or even divided. Do I have to use MPI_Recv() (I have another piece of code which is functional and uses only scatter to divide data equally). 
Could you pint out any problems in the code. Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int root = 0;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int myrank, nprocs;

MPI_Status status;


//variables for prime number calculation
int num1, num2, count, n;


MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

char name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME + 1];
int namelen;

MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &namelen);




cout << "Enter first number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter second number: ";
cin >> num2;



int size = 500;
int size1 = num2 / nprocs;

cout << "The size of each small vector is " << size1 << endl;

auto start = get_time::now();   //start measuring the time


vector<int> sendbuffer(size), recbuffer(size1);  //vectors/buffers involved in the processing


cout << "The prime numbers between " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " are: " << endl;

if (myrank == root)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= num2; ++i)   //array containing all the numbers from which you want to find prime numbers
    {
        sendbuffer[i] = i;
    }

    cout << "Processor " << myrank << " initial data";
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        cout << " " << sendbuffer[i];

    }
    cout << endl;




    MPI_Scatter(&sendbuffer.front(), 125, MPI_INT, &recbuffer.front(), 125, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}



        cout << "Process " << myrank << " now has data ";
        for (int j = 1; j <= size1; ++j)
        {

            cout << " " << recbuffer[j];

        }
        cout << endl;



auto end = get_time::now();
auto diff = end - start;
cout << "Elapsed time is :  " << chrono::duration_cast<ms>(diff).count() << " microseconds " << endl;


MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}`
```